# Ubuntu showing more users on Uptime command

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal

The "uptime" command on my laptop which is running on Ubuntu 20.04 is showing there is 4 users on my laptop:

[image: Uptime command on my PC]

I did search on the internet on how this uptime command works.

According to them, it counts all the active session on terminal.

If I create more window on the terminal the user number will increase.

I created more tabs on my terminal, ran various commands and the number of users remain unchanged.

I close all the tabs (newly created ones + previously opened ones) still it is showing 4 users.

Is my system safe?

update: I added another screenshot, you might want to see
[image: Who command]

Comment: How many are logged in after a reboot?

Comment: 1 user @Artur Meinild

Comment: So then it's not really an issue anymore, right?

Comment: It become 2-3 user after some time.Then again I don't want to share any code or any other data with anyone.According to matigo(1st comment) , I am connected with SSH or SCP or similar kind of thing. I just want a safe PC. @Artur Meinild

Answer (score 0):

You can see who these users are with [the `who` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/who.1.html):

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort
```

If you do not recognise an account, or if you see someone signed in who shouldn't be, then there may be a problem. If you see multiple lines for your own account, that means that you are signed in multiple times.

Comment: Actually there is only 1 user on my PC.No other user is added here

Comment: Then you are signed in 4 times, either through various SSH connections, SCP connections, services, or other means.

Comment: I myself did not connected to any any where with SSH or SCP.The only app now i am running is google chrome. How can I stop this ?

Comment: Who command is not showing  any IP address